# svelte: npm run build doesn't load

Tags: javascript, svelte

i made a little project on sveltejs, i'm trying to build it on production by typing `npm run build`

the command starts, and it show:

```
> defi@0.0.1 build /Users/jacopomosconi/Desktop/svelte
> svelte-kit build

vite v2.6.14 building for production...
✓ 203 modules transformed.
```

then it starts to render the chunks and nothing else happens:

```
rendering chunks (7)...
```

it stops here, i waited also for 3 hours, but nothing happens...
Someone had this issue and know how to solve it?

**update**

i tried to deploy the web-app on a linux server, now when it run npm run build, when it starts to render chunks it give me this error (idk why in local it doesn't show anything) :
[image: error]

Comment: try removing the entire node_modules folder, and reinstalling everything, might be some package going wrong (at the same time update everything to be sure you have the latest in case there were some bugs)

Comment: @StephaneVanraes no, it doesn't change anything, it loads the chunks indefinitely, without giving any errors, but before rendering the chunks I still create the .svelte-kit / build folder

Comment: @StephaneVanraes i tried to deploy my app on a server, now it shows Error: write EPIPE, i updated my question

Comment: Check out this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/121, also try updating SvelteKit to the latest version, Vite 2.7 fixes a lot of issues